# shell script : rsync exclude

Tags: shell, script, rsync, string, exclude

I'm building a shell script and at some point I'm excecuting thie command :

```
rsync -arv --delete --exclude=".svn,*.db,.DS_Store" Source/ Dest/
```

However it seems the my exclusion doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? With a direct command in terminal it works. Perhaps the problem comes from " "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`--exclude=".svn,*.db,.DS_Store"`**

Are you sure the PATTERN in `-exclude=PATTERN` can be a comma-separated list? I'd try splitting it into multiple `-exclude` options

Comment: splitting is the good solution : --exclude=./svn --exclude=*.db ... Thx !

Comment: The shell does NOT expand wildcards in double-quoted strings. The only thing it expands are variables, commands substututions, and arithmetic substitutions.